# How to convert float to fixed point (higher precision) in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement my own fixed point arithmatic in C++ to (later) do higher precision calculations. I was thinking something like

```
class FixedPoint
{
int intPart;
unsigned long long fracPart[some number];
}
```

I think it should work if I - for example for addition - first add two fracPart[some number]'s and if they overflow add 1 to fracPart[some number - 1] and so on.

But I'm stuck at converting a double "d" to a class like this. intPart = d of course works. Then doing

```
double Temp = d - intPart;
```

gives me the fractional part. But how do I correctly assign this to fracPart[0]? In decimal, if long long's had exactly 20 digits, I could just do Temp * 100000000000000000000, so that 0.14 becomes 14000000000000000000. But if in binary I take the mantissa-bits of d (53/54 bits), assign them to fracPart[0] (64 bits), add the hidden bit and shift this left by 13 (or 12 because of the hidden bit), the value is wrong. Nothing I found online so far is helpfull...

Comment: `intPart = d` may overflow; `d` may be way larger than `INT_MAX`

Comment: Forget about fractions, you have more fundamental problems to solve. Are you aware that `double`s can store numerical values that exceed the precision of `int`. What do you expect to happen to your `intPart` when the `double` value is `1e100`, for example? That's 1 followed by a hundred zeroes. Trying to put that into your `intPart` will not work very well.

Comment: Of course floating point values have a bigger range than fixed point values. But IN range, fixed point values can be of more use. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: In my naivety I'd multiply the fractional part (I would use `std::modf`) by my decimal precision and store it in an int truncating the rest. For the integer part I'd use `std::numeric_limits` to see if the `double` value is actually within the representable range

Comment: Multiply `Temp` by 2^64 (or whatever is the number of bits in your `long long`).

Comment: If gcc, you could https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Fixed-Point.html , but it's not available on x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget decimal. Use powers of 2. Your first fractional part should contain bits with the value 2^-1, 2^-2, ... 2^-64. The nice thing about floating point is that you can easily scale your values by powers of two. In other words, subtract the integer part, then multiply with 2^64, then take the next integer part, and so on. Something like this should work for you:

```
#include <cmath>
// using std::floor, std::ldexp
#include <cstdint>
// using std::int64_t, std::uint64_t
#include <cstdio>
// using std::printf


class FixedPoint
{
  std::int64_t ipart;
  std::uint64_t fpart[2];

public:
  explicit FixedPoint(double f) noexcept
  {
    // rounded down so that the fractional part is always positive
    ipart = std::floor(f);
    f -= ipart;
    for(std::uint64_t& fractional: fpart) {
      f = std::ldexp(f, 64);
      fractional = f;
      f -= fractional;
    }
  }
  operator double() const noexcept
  {
    double f = 0.;
    for(int i = 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      f += fpart[i];
      f = std::ldexp(f, -64);
    }
    f += ipart;
    return f;
  }
};



int main()
{
  double f1 = 123.4567;
  FixedPoint p(f1);
  double f2 = p;
  std::printf("%g = %g\n", f1, f2);
}
```

Some final thoughts:

1. I hope you know that there are actual libraries to do this kind of stuff for you? I assume this is just an exercise to get your feet wet with floating point and fixed point. Otherwise cease and desist. ;-)
2. I switched to std::uint64_t because it is way more convenient to have a standard precision in your data type.
3. A downside in using uint64_t is that there is no fast double <-> uint64_t machine instruction in x86_64. Using uint32_t might actually be faster.
4. Using int for the integer part but a larger type for the fractional part is pointless. Due to alignment you just waste 32 bit of space in your struct that you could use for a larger range. Either switch both to 32 bit or use 64 bit for the integer part and keep the size of the fractional part (size of the whole array) a multiple of 64 bit, e.g. 2 x 32 bit
5. Note that `std::frexp` gives you the exponent of a floating point number and a normalized mantissa in the range [0.5, 1) (or zero). That would allow you to replace the integer part with the exponent for an arbitrarily large range without loss of precision. Of course at this point you are just reimplementing extended precision floating point in software.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791500/how-to-convert-float-to-fixed-point-higher-precision-in-c#comment123370703_69792913 `frexp` would fix quite nicely here.

Answer (score 1):

You should

```
#include <boost/multiprecision.hpp>
```

Yes, really. Implementing your own bignum can be fun and instructive, but you will mess up. On something you never thought of. There are a lot of little edge cases and things you need to get right — especially when doing non-integer bignums.

The [Boost Libraries](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) gets it right, and makes it oh so easy to use in your own code.

(You can actually include a more specific file for just the MP type you wish to use, assuming you do not want to include the entire MP library.)

BTW, ***fixed point*** is an integer that is scaled by some *fixed* factor. For example, say you are writing software for the banking industry. You would store values as hundredths of a cent, a (dollar * 10000) factor. What you are trying to do is not fixed point.

Comment: I guess you're right. Got it working "a little bit", but already broke my brain over some edge cases... Can anybody recommend a header-only higher-precision library though? For some reason, I barely get anything third party to work (tried boost already). There's allways some random errors or files/directories not found (I probably should do a clean install (windows), because I did a LOT of installing/deinstalling/reinstalling of serveral visual studio versions and some compilers)...

Comment: Both `cpp_bin_float` and `cpp_dec_float` are header-only Boost bigfloat libraries. :O)

Comment: ... and don't work. I can include them fine, but when compiling, I get errors for other files not found (they are in the same place with the original directory structure)... ;-)

Comment: I can’t help you there. Just unzip Boost somewhere convenient, make sure it is in the include path, and compile. It is possible, as with any library you find on the *net, you may occasionally have to wait a week or so for someone to un-goober the latest release. The prior version of the library would have workable MP stuff while you wait.

Comment: That‘s one problem I‘m having with Visual Studio: Most of the time there just isn‘t a setting for the include path. It just doesn‘t show me most settings. Any idea here? I think I‘ll try a fresh windows/vs-install in a VM. If it works there, my install might be f****d. Otherwise I have no idea what going wrong here…

Comment: Sorry to be so long. You need to modify the directory paths for each project you create in VS. [Here are the docs explaining how](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcpp-directories-property-page?view=msvc-160). If you are using the command line, use the `/I C:\path\to\boost` command-line argument.

Comment: I know. VC++ settings is not showing. Among other things in project properties. New projects work for a while, then it‘s gone… I googled it and there is a workaround, but that doesn‘t do anything for me. Like I said - I guess I should try a completely fresh new install. To much weirdness where simple things don‘t work…

Answer (score 0):

Would using a string be a valid solution in your case? You could overload all the mathematical operation and implement them as you would with paper and pen. It is a lot of work and you may encounter non-trivial efficiency problems, but it may be a viable solution.
It is not clear to me if you are having trouble to convert the double to your struct, but this is a minimal working example that uses the string:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int prec=20;
    double a=1.3235335151561;
    int intpart=std::floor(a);
    double tmp=a-intpart;
    std::ostringstream os;
    os<<std::setprecision(prec)<<tmp;
    std::string str = os.str();
    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
    int frac_part[prec];
    for(int i=0; i<prec; ++i){
        frac_part[i]=(int)str[i+2]-48;
        //jumps 0., and the ascii number for '0' is 48
        std::cout<<frac_part[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";

    }
```

Of course once you have the string using the array for the fractional part is superfluous in my opinion.

Comment: `int ... = std::floor(a);` will break in so many ways for big numbers. Use `lrint` to convert to integers, use `frexp` to decompose a number. `floor` is _not_ for convert a float to integer, it's for flooring a float type _only_.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't think that lrint or llrint are inherently better here.
1. For huge numbers the entire concept of fixed point breaks down anyway. floor followed by cast will give basically the same result as lrint because the float doesn't have any decimal places anyway.
2. If we use lrint, it might round up. Then the fractional part becomes negative and we have to deal with that. It just makes everything more complicated.
IMHO we could use llrint, but only with fesetround(3), meaning rounding to negative infinity.

Comment: @Homer512 Yes, exactly. `frexp`.

Comment: I agree. But I just wanted to show a minimal example connected to the problem the question was addressing. To really be precise you could just directly convert the entire number to a string and take the digits before and after the '.'.  Always assuming that a string-based solution without an external library fits the scope of the problem